# PHP get domain with subdomain from string

Tags: php, function, dns, preg-match, subdomain

Im using the following function to cut domain from string:

```
function get_domain($url)
{
  $pieces = parse_url($url);
  $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
  if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
    return $regs['domain'];
  }
  return false;
}
```

I need to cut **subdomain + domain** how should i change `preg_match` to get it?

**PS** *i was searching solution but everyone wants to cut only domain without sub.*

Comment: Sorry i have found solution, please dont ban

Comment: Then you're free to answer your question and even mark the answer as accepted. It's absolutely legit on SO.

Comment: Its fun, but sollution which i have found is not correct, becase its dont cut `www.` then the problem is still actual.

Comment: I don't get exactly what you want, for me `parse_url` provides the domain name. Please, give some sample input strings and desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't work out the regexp, a more procedural approach might be:

```
$pieces = parse_url($url);
$aDomains = explode('.', $pieces['host']);
$sub = array_shift($aDomains);
$restofdomain = implode($aDomains);
```

...if you're always going to just want the first domain (i.e. it wouldn't work with a root domain like 'somedomain.com'.

Comment: what will be if domain name is somedomain.co.im